# What is the origin of the dash/hypen in the Torah?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

The Torah as it is published in books (that I have seen) is written with hyphens. E.g. Lech-lecha (i.e. the dash between the two words).

What are their origin? Given with the letters of the Torah? Any references on this topic very much appreciated.

EDIT: I originally thought that they were also in the Sefer Torah, but now I mean just in the way it is printed commonly in books. But I add this observation, sometimes one printed version will include three-dashes where another uses only one (e.g. Breisheit-2-3 between the publishing houses of A. BELUM and MOSAD HARAV KUK). But they are still choosing the same words to include dashes between. This makes me think that the number of dashes represents an editorial choice to do with justifying the alignment within a column.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_punctuation#Hyphen_and_maqaf

Comment: In Tanac"h the "dash" is a way of connecting words. In terms of the trope, it indicates that more than one word share the same trope note. In most cases, one (occasionally two) trope notes are on a single word.